# Eclipse Force.com IDE - Can you create an existing salesforce project from file?

Tags: eclipse, mavensmate, force.com-ide

Can the Eclipse Force.com IDE create a force.com project from an existing folder? I have the files pulled from source control but it doesn't seem Eclipse supports it.

I know Mavensmate can do it but can Eclipse do this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the project, go to Force.com and click on "Add Force.com nature".

[image: screenshot of add force.com nature]

Comment: Perfect solution. I had to import the files from git first, like what Nick Cook said, and then added the Force.com Nature.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any built-in UI for that.

I suggest these steps:

- Create a Force.com IDE project from a new or existing org
- Pull the files from your source control system into the src folder of the project folder (that you can find by right-clicking on the project and looking at the Properties that include the Location)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as well, and it requires a slightly different process to usual.

You'd want to use the **Import** feature (File > Import).

If you're using Git, you can select 'Projects from Git', then 'Existing local repository', and go from there.

You can also use this to pull a project from a remote repository.